# Fourier pair of combining time shifting and multiplication in time

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution, discrete-time

There are 2 known properties in DTFT:

1. Time shift corresponds to multiplication with complex exponential 
    $$x[n-k] \rightarrow  e^{-j\omega k}\cdot X_{2\pi}(\omega) $$
2. Multiplication in time corresponds to circular convolution 
    $$x[n]\cdot y[n] \rightarrow{ {\frac {1}{2\pi }}\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }X_{2\pi }(\nu )\cdot Y_{2\pi }(\omega -\nu )d\nu \!}  $$

Now, combining those two we get:
$$x[n]\cdot x[n-k] \rightarrow{ {\frac {1}{2\pi }}\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }e^{-j\nu k}X_{2\pi }(\nu )\cdot X_{2\pi }(\omega -\nu )d\nu \!}  $$

Is there a way to extract the exponential from the integral or at least to shape the integral somehow so that I can first separately calculate the circular convolution of the signal with itself and then do something with the exponential?